# Returning List of values with max property using Comparator

Tags: java, arraylist, java-stream, comparator

What is the best way to get `List<MyCustomObject>` from `List<MyCustomObject>` that have maximum value of some property?

I can write my own `Comparator`:

```
Comparator<MyCustomObject> cmp = Comparator.comparing(MyCustomObject::getIntField);
```

Then use it in a `stream`:

```
Optional<MyCustomObject> max = list.stream().max(cmp);
```

But I'm getting only one element. Is there a simple way to return all `MyCustomObject` that have maximum `IntField` and not just the first one?

Comment: There can not be multiple maximum values, can there? Or do you want all objects having `intField` set to whatever `max(intField)` is?

Comment: Exactly, maybe I have worded my thoughts incorrectly.

Comment: Then you should update your question so it's clear what you are asking without reading the comments. Once you found max, you can stream again: `list.stream().filter(element -> element.equals(max.get())).collect(toList());`

Answer (score 4):

You only know the maximum value of the relevant property after you iterate over all the elements of the `List`, so one way of find the elements having the max value is to group the elements by that property into a sorted Map and get the last value:

```
List<MyCustomObject> max = list.stream()
                               .collect(Collectors.groupingBy (MyCustomObject::getIntField,
                                                               TreeMap::new,
                                                               Collectors.toList ()))
                               .lastEntry ()
                               .getValue ();
```

However, this performs more work then you actually need, and costs `O(NlogN)` due to the sorting. If you don't mind splitting the problem into two steps (first finding the maximum value and then collecting the elements having a property with that value), you'll have better running time (`O(N)`).

Since I don't have your custom object, I couldn't test the above code, but I tested similar code that takes a `Stream` of `String`s and returns all the `String`s having the max length:

```
List<String> max = Stream.of ("ddd","aa","EEEE","a","BB","CCC1")
                         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy (String::length,
                                                         TreeMap::new,
                                                         Collectors.toList ()))
                         .lastEntry ()
                         .getValue ();
System.out.println (max);
```

This returns:

```
[EEEE, CCC1]
```

Comment: You can keep track of the maximum in one pass while iterating, by providing your own `Collector`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50967463/2837741

Answer (score 3):

To avoid two runs, you can provide your own `Collector` to collect the stream.

Let's use

**Sample data class**

```
static class MyCustomObject {
    private int intField;

    MyCustomObject(int field) {
        intField = field;
    }

    public int getIntField() {
        return intField;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Integer.toString(intField);
    }
}
```

What you do to create your own `Collector` is use one of the factory methods, `Collector#of`. We'll use [the more complex one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html#of-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics...-).

This is what it will look like:

```
Collector<MyCustomObject, Intermediate, List<MyCustomObject>> collector
```

with `MyCustomObject` the objects you're collecting, `Intermediate` a class that will store the current maximum and the list of `MyCustomObject`s that had that maximum, and `List<MyCustomObject>>` the desired end result of objects with that maximum.

**Intermediate**

Here's the intermediate class:

```
// simple enough
class Intermediate {
    Integer val = null;
    List<MyCustomObject> objects = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

which will keep the maximum and corresponding objects.
It will be supplied with

```
Supplier<Intermediate> supplier = () -> new Intermediate();
```

(or short Intermediate::new).

**Accumulator**

The `accumulator` needs to accumulate a new `MyCustomObject` into an existing `Intermediate`. This is where the logic calculating the max value comes in.

```
BiConsumer<Intermediate, MyCustomObject> accumulator = (i, c) -> {
    System.out.printf("accumulating %d into %d%n", c.intField, i.value);
    if (i.value != null) {
        if (c.intField > i.value.intValue()) {
            // new max found
            System.out.println("new max " + c.intField);
            i.value = c.intField;
            i.objects.clear();
        } else if (c.intField < i.value) {
            // smaller than previous max: ignore
            return;
        }
    } else {
        i.value = c.intField;
    }
    i.objects.add(c);
};
```

**Combiner**

The `combiner` is used to combine two `Intermediate` values. This is used for parallel streams. If you do the simple test run below you won't trigger it.

```
BinaryOperator<Intermediate> combiner = (i1, i2) -> {
    System.out.printf("combining %d and %d%n", i1.value, i2.value);
    Intermediate result = new Intermediate();
    result.value = Math.max(i1.value, i2.value);
    if (i1.value.intValue() == result.value.intValue()) {
        result.objects.addAll(i1.objects);
    }
    if (i2.value.intValue() == result.value.intValue()) {
        result.objects.addAll(i2.objects);
    }
    return result;
};
```

**Finisher**

Finally, we need to extract the `List<MyCustomObject>` we really want from the final `Intermediate` using the `finisher`

```
Function<Intermediate, List<MyCustomObject>> finisher = i -> i.objects;
```

This all comes together for the `Collector`

```
Collector<MyCustomObject, Intermediate, List<MyCustomObject>> collector =
    Collector.of(supplier, accumulator, combiner, finisher);
```

And for a simple test run

```
List<MyCustomObject> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        list.add(new MyCustomObject(i));
    }
}
Collections.shuffle(list);

System.out.println(list.stream().collect(collector));
```

Output

> [9, 9, 9]

We do only iterate once, so it should be O(n) as the solution with two runs; I'm not entirely sure about this though because of all the adding to lists that happens in the intermediate steps.

[See it tied together](https://ideone.com/8urTZ7)

For an actual `Comparator` version, you'd have to also adjust the `Intermediate` object; then it's probably best to use a `MyCustomObject` in the `Intermediate` to use for the comparison as well.

[Here is a version for this](https://ideone.com/H3lQy7), including a refactoring of the accumulator into the `Intermediate` class.

In the end, it boils down to this factory method:

```
public static <T> Collector<T, ?, List<T>> max(Comparator<T> compare) {
    class Intermediate {
        T value = null;
        List<T> objects = new ArrayList<>();

        void add(T c) {
            if (objects.isEmpty()) {
                value = c;
            } else {
                int compareResult = compare.compare(c, objects.get(0));
                if (compareResult > 0) {
                    // new max found
                    System.out.println("new max " + c + ", dropping " + objects.size() + " objects");
                    value = c;
                    objects.clear();
                } else if (compareResult < 0) {
                    return;
                }
            }
            objects.add(c);
        }
    }
    BinaryOperator<Intermediate> combiner = (i1, i2) -> {
        Optional<T> max = Stream.of(i1, i2).filter(Objects::nonNull).filter(i -> !i.objects.isEmpty())
                .map(i -> i.objects.get(0)).max(compare);
        Intermediate r = max.map(m -> {
            Intermediate result = new Intermediate();
            result.value = max.get();
            if (i1 != null && i1.value != null && compare.compare(i1.value, m) == 0) {
                result.objects.addAll(i1.objects);
            }
            if (i2 != null && i2.value != null && compare.compare(i2.value, m) == 0) {
                result.objects.addAll(i2.objects);
            }
            return result;
        }).orElse(null);
        System.out.printf("combining %s and %s - result %s%n", i1, i2, r);
        return r;
    };
    return Collector.of(Intermediate::new, Intermediate::add, combiner, i -> i.objects);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I offer this simple solution. First retrieve max element from the given list `objs`. And then retrieve all elements, that equal to max.

```
public static <T> List<T> getAllMax(List<T> objs, Comparator<T> comp) {
    T max = objs.stream().max(comp).get();
    return objs.stream().filter(e -> comp.compare(e, max) == 0).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

We loop given list only twice without extra memory allocation. Therefore we have **O(n)** complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Code snippet for this problem：

```
List<MyCustomObject> maxList = new ArrayList<>();
MyCustomObject max = list.stream().max(cmp).orElse(null);
if (null != max) {
   maxList.add(max);
   list.remove(max);
   while (list.stream().max(cmp).orElse(null) != null) {
     maxList.add(max);
     list.remove(max);
  }
}
```